# How can I add two lines off the x and y axes to specify a certain point?

Tags: r

I'm plotting two sets of data using the `plot` function. They intersect at a certain point. I want to indicate this point with a dotted line from the x axis to that point, and a dotted line from the y axis to that point. Is this possible with R?

Comment: Take a look at `?abline`

Comment: I did, but that seems to only work for adding lines to your plot, as in plotting another series that happens to be a line. Unless I misunderstood it?

Comment: You'll need to know what the intersection point is and then add the appropriate `abline`. You'll need to perform that calculation outside the `plot` call.

Comment: Ah.. I just re-read the help for abline, and I was able to get the line at a certain point, like you said doing the calculation elsewhere. I used `abline(h=300, lty=3)`, and that drew a horizontal line at y=300. Thanks, I seemed to have overlooked this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set.seed(1492)

dat1 <- data.frame(x=c(sample(1:100, 100, replace=TRUE), 3),
                   y=c(sample(1:200, 100, replace=TRUE), 4))

dat2 <- data.frame(x=c(sample(1:100, 100, replace=TRUE), 3),
                   y=c(sample(1:200, 100, replace=TRUE), 4))


dat1[dat1$x == dat2$x & dat1$y == dat2$y,]

plot(dat1, col="blue")
points(dat2, col="red", add=TRUE)
abline(h=dat1[dat1$x == dat2$x & dat1$y == dat2$y,]$y, lty=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the `abline` function with `h` and `v` parameters for the horizontal and vertical values, and `lty` = 3 for a dotted line.

```
plot(c(-2,3), c(-1,5), type = "n", xlab = "x", ylab = "y", asp = 1)
abline(h = 3, v = 2, lty = 3)
```

[image: abline example]